# accessing attribute directive values using controller as

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to do it Without controller as:

**html**
Let's assume I have a directive named `ngUpperCase(either true or false)`

```
<div ng-controller="myControl" >
 <input type="text" ng-upper-case="isGiant" >
</div>
```

**Js**

```
myApp.directive('ngUpperCase',function(){
  return{
     restrict:'A',
     priority:0,
     link:function($scope,element,attr){
         //---to retrieve value
         var val = $scope[attr.ngUpperCase];
         var anotherVal = $scope.$eval(attr.ngUpperCase);
         $scope.$watch(attr.ngUpperCase,function(val){
            //---to watch
         })
     }
  };
})
```

How to make the directive if I'm using something like this?

```
<div ng-controller="myControl as ctl" >
 <input type="text" ng-upper-case="ctl.isGiant" >
</div>
```

Comment: What you have should work. What problems are you having?

Comment: it always returns undefined when using "controller as"

Comment: share your contrller code, how you defined the controller ?
And instead of this you can directly pass scope variable in directive as an attribute.

Comment: You're doing nothing with val and anotherval, what doesn't work? You want to make an input value changed to uppercase based on a boolean?

Comment: in your controller, you should define "isGaint" as `this.isGaint` instead of `$scope.isGaint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not very clear what you want to achieve, here is an example of doing what I understand you need: changing an input value to upper or lower case depending on a variable:

```js
function ngUpperCase() {
  return{
     restrict:'A',
     priority:0,
     link:function($scope,element,attr){
         //---to retrieve value
         var val = $scope[attr.ngUpperCase];
         var anotherVal = $scope.$eval(attr.ngUpperCase);
         $scope.$watch(attr.ngUpperCase,function(val){
            if(val) {
              element[0].value = element[0].value.toUpperCase();
            } else {
              element[0].value = element[0].value.toLowerCase();
            }
         })
     }
  }
}
function myController() {
  this.isGiant = true;
}
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', myController)
    .directive('ngUpperCase', ngUpperCase);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController as ctl" >
    <a href="" ng-click="ctl.isGiant = false">lower case</a><br>
    <a href="" ng-click="ctl.isGiant = true">upper case</a>
    <input type="text" ng-upper-case="ctl.isGiant" value="TeStiNg123" >
  </div>
</div>
```